# VBA date returns 1/1/1900

Tags: vba

I am trying to set a cell value to today's date. I am using the Date function to do so.

However, for some reason, the cell always shows 1/1/1900. `Debug.Print Date` prints out a correct date. I even tried to create a new date and convert it into a string, but when it passes on to the cell value it becomes an incorrect date again.

```
Sub CreateAndLabelNewSheet()
Worksheets.Add
Dim ds As Date
ds = Date
Dim dString As String
dString = ds
Debug.Print "String" & dString
Range("B2").Value = dString
Debug.Print Range("B2").Value
Debug.Print ds
Debug.Print Date
End Sub
```

Basically, the output is:

> String6/1/2019
>   12/31/1899
>   6/1/2019
>   6/1/2019

So, both `ds` and `dString`, as well as `Debug.Print Date` works correctly, but the cell value is incorrect.

Comment: Try `Range("B2").Value = ds` instead.  You are currently assigning a String, but an Excel cell holding a date is actually a number - the count of days since 1900.  Let us know if that helps!  Also, welcome to the site!

Comment: in addition to what @cxw commented please check whether Excel Option Transition formula  entry is checked and clear it.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the site! I just ran your code in a new Excel spreadsheet and it seems to be working fine. The cell had today's date (albeit in the American format like the second debug line) and the debug output gave me `String2/06/2019
6/02/2019 
2/06/2019 
2/06/2019`

Comment: Thank you guys for a warm welcome. I have tried Range("B2").Value = ds. Same problem, that's why I tried a String. @AhmedAU Can you please tell me how to check it?

Comment: @AhmedAU I've enabled/disabled that option, and in my case doesn't make any difference, i get the results you would expect from above, as Dog Lover did as well. Erin, if you want to check the option is under `Options > Advanced > scroll to bottom`.

Comment: What is the number format of the cell?  If you have set it to `"01/01/1900"` then it will show that, regardless of the value of the cell.

Comment: What do you get if you use `Debug.Print Range("B2").Value2` (the "Value2" isn't a typo)